# Topic targeting keywords with commas split into two keywords during validation

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api

When searching for keywords and keyword suggestions, there are some keywords that facebook returns, such as "**#Dude, Where's My Car?**" that have commas in them. While trying to validate them, these keywords get split in two. I've tried a number of things from slashes to urlencode to keep them from getting separated, but I haven't been successful. Anyone have any ideas?

The below url part returns valid for every keyword but not for `%23Dude%2c+Where%27s+My+Car%3f`

```
search?type=adkeywordvalid&keyword_list=Hey+Dude+Wheres+My+Car,Dude+Where+Is+My+Car,Dude+Wheres+My+Car,%23Dude%2c+Where%27s+My+Car%3f,Dude+Wheres+My+Car+Then,Dude+Where039s+My+Car,%23The+Hangover,%23Harold+%26+Kumar+Go+to+White+Castle
```

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. It appears to be a Facebook API bug. 
I have logged it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149123891917269.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's not so much a bug as a documentation issue.
You just need to surround the keyword by urlencoded quotes AND square brackets:

```
["#Dude, Where's My Car?"]
```

becomes

```
%5B%22%23Dude%2C%20Where's%20My%20Car%3F%22%5D
```

... and the result is correct:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
     "name": "#Dude, Where's My Car?",
     "valid": true,
         "id": "6003406131991"
      }
   ]
}
```